If the selected record is on the 2nd page of the Angular Data Table, can we navigate to that page by default?
I have an Angular Data Table that displays a list of organizations. It shows a maximum of 5 organizations per page. However, the default selected organization index is 7, which means it is on the 2nd page. Therefore, I want the table to automatically display the page where the selected organization is located. In my code, the table currently only displays the first page. When I click the next button in the table, it navigates to the 2nd page and displays the selected organization.
This is my angular data table html
<div>
    <div class="ion-padding">
      <table   class="row-border hover" datatable="ng" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptionForListTable()" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">
        <thead class="tr">
          <tr class="tr">
            <th class="name" datatableOrder="asc">Name</th>
            <th>Organisation Type</th>
            <th>Industry Type</th>
            <th class="class">Action</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tr-r">
          <tr *ngFor="let org of orgList; let i = index" (click)="selectedOrg(org.id)"
          [ngClass]="{'select-row': org.id === selectedOrgId }">
            <td>{{org.name}}
            </td>
            <td>{{org.orgTypeName}}</td>
            <td>{{org.industryTypeName}}</td>
            <td>
              <ion-icon id="view{{i}}" class="view" title="View" name="eye-outline" expand="block"
                (click)="getOrgDetails(org.id, true)"></ion-icon>
              <ion-icon id="edit{{i}}" class="edit" title="Edit" name="pencil-outline" (click)="getOrgDetails(org.id, false)"
                expand="block"></ion-icon>
              <ion-icon id="delete{{i}}" class="trash" title="Delete" name='trash' (click)="presentDeleteAlert(org.id)"></ion-icon>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

and calculated the page number of the selected organization's location

      ngOninit(){
            this.orgId = navigation.extras.state['orgId'];
            this.selectedOrgId = this.orgId
            
            
            const selectedIndex = this.findOrgIndex(this.selectedOrgId)
            console.log("selectedIndex", selectedIndex);

            // this.orgList.indexOf(this.selectedOrgId);
            const pageNumber = Math.floor(selectedIndex / this.pageSize) + 1;
            console.log("pageNumber", pageNumber);

            // Navigate to the calculated page
            this.navigateToPage(pageNumber);
     }

 findOrgIndex(selectedOrg: any): number {
    return this.orgList.findIndex(org => org.id === selectedOrg); // Replace 'id' with the actual unique identifier property
  }
  navigateToPage(pageNumber: number) {
    // Assuming you have a property called currentPage in your component
    this.currentPage = pageNumber;
    console.log("this.currentPage",this.currentPage)
  }

page size is 5,
index is 7
found page number of selected org it is 2, but its not navigate to that page. How to navigate to 2 nd page in angular data table.
Therefore, I want the table to automatically display the page where the selected organization is located.

You can manage pagination by using state save datatable will provide you that functionality
you can set dtoption like this
        stateSave: true,
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "pageLength":15,
        "oSearch": {"sSearch": ""},
        stateSaveCallback: function(settings,data) {
            localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_' + settings.sInstance, JSON.stringify(data))
        },
        stateLoadCallback: function(settings) {
            return JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'DataTables_' + settings.sInstance ))
        },

For more info you can check on website
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html
